# static files in django - should be inside app_name folder?

Tags: django

Inside my app folder I have folder `static` and inside `css`, `js`, and `img` folders.

It is ok or should I keep it like this `static -> app_name -> css,js,img`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar to with templates it is recommended to namespace your static resources with a directory inside of static with the app name. However this is really only useful if the application is going to be reused on multiple projects with the possibility overriding the static resources in other deployments. Since Django encourages building all applications as reusable components  this inner directory is recommended but again not required.

Answer (score 0):

The static files are can be in app folder or project folder or in sub folders of your project folder. But You must tell the program that where these files are.So You have to mention it in the SETTINGS file.